# A fixed point theorem for the unit disk?

Tags: fixed-point-theorems

In *Dynamical Systems and Ergodic Theory* by Pollicott and Yuri, there is an easy, one dimensional, fixed point theorem:

> If $T$ is a continuous map on a closed interval $J$ so that $T(J)\supseteq J$, 
>   then $T$ has a fixed point.

Here the space is mapped *onto* itself, in contrast to the "usual" fixed point theorems where it is mapped *into* itself.

Out of idle curiosity, I wonder if it's true in higher dimensions.
To be concrete, let $D=\{(x,y): x^2+y^2\leq 1\}$ be the closed unit disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$. 
Suppose that $T$ is continuous on $D$ and $T(D)\supseteq D$, does $T$ have 
a fixed point?

If $T$ is one-to-one, for instance, this follows by applying [Kakutani's fixed point 
theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kakutani_fixed-point_theorem) to the set valued map $x\mapsto T^{-1}(\{x\})$ on $D$. 
But I'm not sure whether the result holds in general.

Comment: Upvote for "out of idle curiosity"!

Comment: Isn't the proof the same as for Brouwer's fixed point theorem?  Project $z \in D$ to its "shadow" on $\partial D$ if you put a light source at $f(z)$.  This would give a continuous map $D \rightarrow \partial D$ that fixes $\partial D$ if $f$ has no fixed points.

Comment: ...no that doesn't work.  It doesn't have to be continuous at $\partial D$.

Comment: Could we perhaps map $z \in D$ to *both* intersection points of the line connecting $z$ and $f(z)$ on $\partial D$.  That would give a map $D \rightarrow \partial D \times \partial D$ and $\partial D$ would map to a non-contractible curve on this torus.

Comment: @WimC Thanks very much for your input. I am slower than you are, and I'm still processing the "no that doesn't work" comment. If you come up with a solution, please post it as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not true, as I convinced myself using a cork coaster not unlike [these](http://img0.etsystatic.com/il_fullxfull.189072552.jpg). A counterexample is given by a map that maps the upper third of the disk to the lower half, the lower third to the upper half, and the middle third to a band that connects the two outside the disk.

Comment: You just beat me to it!

Comment: Very nice!  Coasters are indispensible math tools.

Comment: @joriki Thanks very much for this. I never would have thought of this on my own.